# Issue an alert in React Native without dismissing the keyboard

Tags: react-native

In the code below, when you click on the button, the alert pops up and the keyboard is dismissed. Is there a way to issue an alert in React Native without dismissing the keyboard?

https://snack.expo.io/Hywcjv7WL

```
import * as React from "react";
import { Alert, TextInput, View, Button, StyleSheet } from "react-native";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.input}
          autoFocus={true}
        />
        <Button
          title="Press Me"
          onPress={() => {
            Alert.alert("Hello")
          }}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    padding: 40
  },
  input: {
    padding: 10,
    borderWidth: 1
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do that programmatically by using ref.

```
<TextInput
    style={styles.textInput}
    ref={ref => this.textInputRef = ref}
    placeholder="Quiz Deck Title"
    autoFocus={true}
    value={this.state.title}
    onChangeText={(title) => this.controlledTextInput(title)}
/>
```

Then you can use `this.textInputRef.focus()` and trigger this after you dismiss the alert message.

Actually, also you can trigger this by using this code.

```
Alert.alert(
  'Alert Title',
  'My Alert Msg',
  [
    {text: 'Ask me later', onPress: () => console.log('Ask me later pressed')},
    {
      text: 'Cancel',
      onPress: () => console.log('Cancel Pressed'),
      style: 'cancel',
    },
    {text: 'OK', onPress: () => console.log('OK Pressed')},
  ],
  {cancelable: false},
);
```

Comment: By the way this is just opens the keyboard back after you dismiss the keyboard. Not exactly what you ask for but might work as well since not sure if there is a way to keep the keyboard on with the alert pop-up.